# Определение массива энумератором

Tags: c, массивы, const

Есть следующий код. Здравствуйте.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum page_string_name{
    STRING_A,
    STRING_B,
    STRINGS_COUNT,
}page_string_name;

typedef enum page_name{
    PAGE_A,
    PAGE_B,
    PAGE_COUNT,
}page_name;

typedef const char* const page_string;
typedef page_string const* const page;

page_string page_1[STRINGS_COUNT] = {
    "Text 1 \n",
    "Text 2 \n",
};

page_string page_2[STRINGS_COUNT] = {
    "Text 3 \n",
    "Text 4 \n",
};

page page_list[PAGE_COUNT] = {
    page_1,
    page_2,
};

int main()
{
    printf("%s", page_list[PAGE_A][STRING_A]);
    printf("%s", page_list[PAGE_A][STRING_B]);
    printf("%s", page_list[PAGE_B][STRING_A]);
    printf("%s", page_list[PAGE_B][STRING_B]);
    return 0;
}
```

Но подобное определение `page_1` и `page_2` мне не нравится и это не очень удобно, я бы хотел это делать вот так:

```
page_string page_1[STRINGS_COUNT];
page_1[STRING_A] = "Text 1";
page_1[STRING_B] = "Text 2";
```

Но это почему-то вызывает ошибку redefinition of page_1

```
redefinition of 'page_1' with a different type: 'int [0]' vs 'page_string [2]
```

и предупреждение о отсутствие типа в объявлении page_1.

```
type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] page_1[STRING_A] 
 = "Text 1";
```

Мне очень не хочется делать это способом как в начале примера, т.к. может вызвать путаницу с энумами, которую потом будешь высматривать часами (массивы будут большими).
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page_string page_1[STRINGS_COUNT] = {
    [STRING_A] = "Text 1 \n",
    [STRING_B] = "Text 2 \n",
};

page_string page_2[STRINGS_COUNT] = {
    [STRING_A] = "Text 3 \n",
    [STRING_B] = "Text 4 \n",
};
```